# GRE scores per section and their importance for PhD admissions in CS/E.Engineering

Tags: phd, gre

What scores are generally expected *per section* (AW/quantitative/verbal) to get my applications evaluated in top/good grad schools?
Also, would achieving even better scores be a "plus" or it won't matter at all/that much?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My top-10 CS department does not require GRE scores at all.

For applicants that send them in anyway, the only scores that provide useful information are low scores.  Anything below about the 50th percentile is a red flag.

You are aiming at the wrong target.  Top grad schools are looking for strong evidence of promise as an independent researcher.  Test scores do not provide that evidence.

Comment: I am just getting a bit anxious about the GRE exam. I will study approximately a month for it and i am not a native english speaker, so i am most worried about AW/verbal. I am also wondering if those sections distract me too much from quantitative, in which i believe i ought to get a near perfect score!

Comment: At least in my department, the only way your GRE verbal score can affect your chances is by being _really_ low (<20%ile).